# Can I obtain/see the metadata of the original word document which has now been saved as a PDF

Tags: pdf, metadata

I have a PDF document which has been provided to me, however, I am unable to get the Word document of that document to check the metadata of the document.I have been provided with the PDF. I have checked the inspect tab which tells me the state the date it was created as a PDF and when it was modified. However, I want the original meta data from the word document. Is it possible to retrieve that data/ does the meta data gets transferred from the word document to PDF. Hope someone can help.

Comment: It depends on how the PDF has been made, whether original metadata got transferred to the PDF. You might open the PDF in Acrobat, and look out for the additional metadata (which displays XMP information), or you could search for XMP information in the PDF.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Not sure how to search for the additional meta data. I have tried but unsuccessful so far. Are you able to give some instructions as to where to look? Many thanks,Ronnie

Comment: I am referring to the "Additional Metadata" button in the document properties dialog, "Description" tab.

Comment: Max- I am unsure how to access this additional metadata dialog, are you able to help.